# What is a significance of 9.536743e-7?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, bit

I realized that outputs of a continuous function (takes a vector, returns a scalar) that I wrote in python are discretized at the resolution of 9.536743e-7.

I googled this number and learned that some websites say that 1bit=9.536743e-7 megabit. Isn't 1 bit = 10e-8 megabit? Why am I seeing this number everywhere and why do I see it in my code?

My code was written in jax.numpy.

Comment: Seems like the order of magnitude of `float` [epsilon](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon), but the value isn't quite right: https://godbolt.org/z/3Geo4bxW6

Comment: It is exactly 8 epsilon.  Which is what you'd expect your discretization to be once you're in the range from 8 to 16.

Comment: "mega" is often ambiguous in computer contexts: do they mean 10\**6, or 2\**20 (which is close to a million)? In this case, they meant the latter: 1/2\**20 = 9.5367431640625e-07.

Comment: Its a negative exponent `e-7`, `0.0000001` (almost - its a binary double that doesn't quie map to the base 10 world). `e-6` would be micro, `e-7` is 100 nano. I seem to recall that Microsoft's 64 bit time is 100 nano resolution.

Comment: To follow on @TimPeters comment, the correct terminology is Megabit for 10**6 and Mebibit for 2**20. Unfortunately, the terms are not used consistently.

Comment: Aha very interesting. In my context, the function was a cost function, and the unwanted discretization made the function look like it has steps near the optimal point, which was very confusing!

Comment: They aren't used consistently because (IMO) it's a bit ridiculous to assume that they had to be consistent with SI. Bits and bytes are not SI units, and I don't think anyone ever had a problem with 1KB == 1,024 bytes, etc, until hard-drive manufacturers started being pedantic so that they could sell a "20MB" hard drive that only stored 20,000,000 bytes, instead of 25,165,824 bytes.

Comment: Oops, need to rewrite that. Megabit `10**6` and Mebibit is `2**20`.

Comment: @tdelaney "Mebibit"? NEVER heard it in 35 years in tech.  It probably IS "correct", but the world is not.  lol

Comment: @Andrew, it came into use in the 90's. Since RAM capacity grows by adding an address or data line, we got to calling multiples of 2 "kilo", "mega", "giga" and etc. But it was never really the decimal numbers. Storage, networks, etc... kept with the real decimal 10 based stuff. Mostly. Operating system and performance tools might mix those numbers messing up comparisons and leave you wondering why your harddrive was smaller than claimed.

Comment: @Andrew, no, the 9.5367431640625e-07 I gave is the exact decimal value of 1/2\**20. One way to verify that: `Fraction(95367431640625, 10**20) == Fraction(1, 2**20)` displays `True`.

Comment: @Tim Peters:  Sorry, you're right--deleting the post/thread to get rid of the noise...

Answer (score 0):

When discussing memory, "mega" typically means 2^20 = 1048576.  And, yes: `1/1048576 = 9.536743e-7`

Whereas, when discussing bandwidth/speed, "mega" typically means 1000000.  However, when discussing memory, bytes are usually used (vs bits for bandwidth/speed); so that part is strange.  So I suppose you could say the time for 1 bit on a  1 megabit link is 9.536743e-7 seconds.  But it is atypical at best.  I don't see how this 1/x thinking would apply to memory.

Note that this number cannot be represented exactly as a float; here is the closest 64 bit float value:

```
>>> print "%1000.1000f\n" % 0.000000953674316
0.0000009536743159999999753652735225151193532155957655049860477447509765625000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

>>>
```

Comment: 9.536743e-7 can't be represented exactly as a binary float, but 1/2\**20 certainly can be. I gave its exact decimal value before in a comment: 9.5367431640625e-07.